# How to make Typescript Dojo Widget Newable?

Tags: javascript, dojo, typescript

From within an existing Dojo widget, I want to create an instance of some other widget, which has been transpiled from TypeScript. Sounds simple -- but for some reason the transpiled widget is not "newable", unless I specify the classname twice. I can't update all of that existing code, so I need the transpiled widget to be "newable".

Here is the very simple **MyTypeScriptWidget.ts**:

```
import _WidgetBase = require("dijit/_WidgetBase");
export class MyTypeScriptWidget extends dijit._WidgetBase 
{
  constructor(params?: Object, srcNodeRef?: HTMLElement) 
  {
    super(params, srcNodeRef);
  }
}
```

Then, over in the existing Dojo JavaScript (not TypeScript) widget, I want to new up an instance of MyTypeScriptWidget. So, here's what I have to do in **MyJavaScriptWidget.js**

```
var myInstance = new MyTypeScriptWidget.MyTypeScriptWidget();
```

Notice how I have to type it twice? Why? What am I doing wrong? How can I change **MyTypeScriptWidget.ts** so that **MyJavaScriptWidget.ts** can use AMD to create an instance like I did before, like this:

```
define(['dijit/_WidgetBase', 'tool/MyTypeScriptWidget'], function(_WidgetBase, MyTypeScriptWidget) {

  return declare([_WidgetBase], {
    var myInstance = new MyTypeScriptWidget();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In TypeScript, `export` normally defines members on the module's export object.  If you want to define a single thing to be exported, you need to use [`export =`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#modules-export-).

```
class MyTypeScriptWidget ... {
    ...
}

export = MyTypeScriptWidget;
```

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely 100% correct, and that worked for me. I feel so stupid! So, if I'm developing according to one-class-per-file, I want to use that code. If I want to have several classes per file, I would have to use the namespace.classname convention. Ugh, now I have to understand how this related to modules...

Comment: `export foo` is typically more useful for things like utility modules where you expect to return an object containing various functions.  then you can just do `export function foo`, `export function bar`, etc.